# Parsing json with lens-aeson

Tags: json, haskell, haskell-lens

Trying out Edward Kmett's mind expanding lens and lens-aeson package. Here's a warmup

```
s = "{ \"somekey\" : [ { \"deeperkey\" : 1} , {\"deeperkey\": 2, \"otherkey\":3}]}
```

The desired result is

```
[(1, Nothing), (2, Just 3)]
```

I can make a little progress with

```
import Control.Lens.Aeson
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Vector as V

λ> s ^. key "somekey" . _Array . to V.toList >>= (^.. key "deeperkey" . _Number)
[1,2]
```

But I so far haven't figure out how to work the combinators hard enough to get the correct answer. 
I most probably involves the fragment ' key "otherkey" '. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
s ^.. key "somekey" . _Array . traverse 
                    . to (\o -> ( o ^?! key "deeperkey" . _Number
                                , o ^?  key "otherkey"  . _Number
                                )
                         )
```

With `(^..)` to get multiple elements from the `traverse` `Traversal` and `Array` to match on the multiple values in the `"somekey"` slot. Technically the `key "deeperkey"` should be allowed to fail, but based on your return type you're making strong assumptions that it doesn't---so we use `(^?!)` to do the failing `(^?)` without a `Maybe` monad for protection.

Comment: Super close!

    `s ^.. key "somekey" . _Array . traverse . to (\o -> (o ^?! key "deeperkey" . _Number, o ^? key "otherkey" . _Number))` yields
    `[(1,Nothing),(2,Just 3)]`.
 If you edit your answer for future readers, I'll mark the question answered.

Comment: Missed one—fixed now!